# Retrieve offline_access token from keycloak

Tags: keycloak, access-token, openid

I'm trying to retrieve a offline_token from keycloak (version 19) from command line but I always obtain an access_token based on my expiration default time (300 secons).

I've read the Keycloak official documentation without no success. I add to the user the offline_access role and the same client scope (offline_access, default .ode) to the client that I try to obtain the offline access token. When I retrive it appears a line in a consent section on the user profile but with no grants, so I suspect that I'm missing some step or configuration.

My code is:

```
curl --location --request POST http://localhost:8080/realms/adnetwork/protocol/openid-connect/token \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=someclientid' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=someclientsecret' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid offline_access' \
--data-urlencode 'username=someuser' \
--data-urlencode 'password=somepass'
```

After this call, I take the access_token field but it expires in the next 5 minutes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `access_token` won't be the offline token. It's the refresh token which will be the actual offline-token. An offline-token doesn't have the `exp` claim.
With the offline-token, a (confidential!) client will be able to get a valid `access_token` for this user at any time, even when the user is not online (= offline), thus the name.

Comment: I have tried what you mentioned and it worked for me. Thank you!

My intention was to create a use case where it was not necessary to renew the access_token for a client that does not have oauth2 in its connection to my Keycloak Client. I understand that it is not possible, so I will look for alternatives.